# Headers are not working, showing a blank page instead of 404

Tags: php, apache, redirect, header

Anyone could help me understand why the headers that throw HTTP redirect won't work in this code? If my route works, then it shows the page as supposed. But when the route doesn't match (exist), it won't throw the 404 page, only showing a blank page.

Could it be related to WAMP settings (Apache, PHP.ini) or could it be related to the .htaccess file?

I am using the AltoRouter class from dannyvankooten @https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter

Thanks!

Front controller (index.php):

```
$router = new router();

$router->map('GET', '/welcome/', 'WelcomeController#hello', 'welcome_hello');

$match = $router->match();

if ($match === false)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}

else
{
    list($controller, $action) = explode('#', $match['target']);

    if (is_callable(array($controller, $action)))
    {
        $obj = new $controller();
        call_user_func_array(array($obj, $action), array($match['params']));
    }

    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
    }
}
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this on my local machine using your code.  Note however I had to make the following changes:

The root class of this package is `new AltoRouter()` not `new router()`, is there a small chance you've another router() class that could have similar methods?

The header might still be being set to 404 but no custom content is served up to display on the page. Browsers display different error pages in different situations.  In the following example I serve up a custom message to confirm.
Since browsers respond differently and can cache responses etc. I tested this using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) - you could use many other tools though.

This code sample worked successfully for me:

```
$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map('GET', '/welcome/', 'WelcomeController#hello', 'welcome_hello');

$match = $router->match();
// var_dump($match); // dump or breakpoint/xdebug here to avoid testing other logic.

if ($match === false)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "That URL doesn't exist";
} else {
    echo "Route matched!<br>";
    echo "<pre>".print_r($match, true)."</pre>";
}
```

And I ran the file with: `php -S localhost:8088 alto_router.php`

```
GET localhost:8088/Welcome -> 404
GET localhost:8088/welcome -> 404
GET localhost:8088/Welcome/ -> 404
GET localhost:8088/welcome/ -> 200
```

Comment: I renamed AltoRouter class to Router, that is why I called it with $router = new Router();

Comment: Unrelated, I'd recommend re-aliasing rather than renaming. It means the 3rd party code remains unchanged. e.g.  `use AltoRouter as MyRouter`

Comment: Does the supplied example work separate from the apache config (i.e. using PHP's built in server?)  If so it would indicate an Apache configuration issue rather than a router issue.